# Double callback on error

Tags: mocha.js, stylus

When testing stylus and the assertion throws, it calls the callback a second time with the Assertion error:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect,
    stylus = require('stylus'),
    i = 0

describe('test stylus', function(){
    it('calls back', function(done){
        stylus('p\n\tcolor white').render(function(err,css){
            i++;
            console.log('callback', i) //logs twice
            expect(css).equal('p\n\t{ color: bad;\n}')
            done()
        })
    })
})
```

I'm using this to work-around:

```
describe('test stylus', function(){
    it('calls back', function(done){
        stylus('p\n\tcolor white').render(function(err,css){
            try {
                expect(css).equal('p\n\t{ color: bad;\n}')
            } catch(e) {
                done(e)
            }   
        })
    })
})
```

I'm thinking it's a stylus bug to re-call the callback. Or Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hypothesis is correct. Here is the [code](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/74b61ee33d93fbe39682f825ed1bba9770258be3/lib/renderer.js) in stylus:

```
Renderer.prototype.render = function(fn){

  // ...

  try {

    // ...

    var listeners = this.listeners('end');
    if (fn) listeners.push(fn);
    for (var i = 0, len = listeners.length; i < len; i++) {
      var ret = listeners[i](null, css); // Called here once.
      if (ret) css = ret;
    }
    if (!fn) return css;
  } catch (err) {
    var options = {};
    options.input = err.input || this.str;
    options.filename = err.filename || this.options.filename;
    options.lineno = err.lineno || parser.lexer.lineno;
    if (!fn) throw utils.formatException(err, options);
    // Called here a second time if there is an exception.
    fn(utils.formatException(err, options));
  }
};
```

`fn` is the callback. It is added to `listeners` and will be called once as part of the loop that calls all listeners. If the callback raises an exception there, then it is called *again* as part of the exception handling.

Comment: Given that stylus render is typically a build-time function, I suppose that's probably acceptable behavior.